# Custom Security Plugin for Apache Ignite

Tags: java, ignite

I am trying to use Apache Ignite as in-memory database.
To enable the security, I created own security plugin by following link   http://smartkey.co.uk/development/securing-an-apache-ignite-cluster/

### Below are my implementation details

```
public class IgniteSecurityConfiguration implements PluginConfiguration{
        public class<? extends PluginProvider> providerClass(){
          return IgniteSecurityProvider.class;
        }
    }
public class IgniteSecurityProvider implements PluginProvider{
    @Override
    public IgnitePlugin plugin(){
      return new CASCachePlugin();
    }
} 

    public Object createComponent(PluginContext pluginContext, Class aClass){
       if(aClass.isAssignableFrom(GridSecuriytProcessor.class)){
       return new PasswordSecurityProcessor();
    } else {return null;}
   }

public class PasswordSecurityProcessor implements GridSecurityProcessor,IgnitePlugin
{
@Override
public SecurityContext authenticateNode(ClusterNode clusterNode, SecurityCredentials securityCredentials){
   return new SecurityContext(){
         public SecuritySubject subject(){
           return new SecuritySubjext(){
             //implement methods
           };
         }
        //other implementation methods
    };
}
```

getting exception when I am starting ignite using examples/config/example-ignite.xml

> Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start SPI: TcpDiscoverySpi
>   at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi (GridManagerAdapter.java:300)
>   ...
>   ...
>   Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Failed to authenticate local node( will shutdown local node).
>   at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.localAuthentication(ServerImpl.java:975)
>   at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.joinTopology(ServerImpl.java:863)
>   .....
>   Cuased by class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to serialize objext: com.x.x.x.PasswordSecurityProcessor
>   at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshller.marshl0(JDkMarahsller.java:85)

**Any idea on what I am missing?**
Tried the PasswordSecurityProcessor class to implement Serializable but still it did not help.

Comment: Apache Ignite does not have version 2.1.3

Comment: kindly reopen as the question is rephrased.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ignite does not provide security capabilities out of the box, you need to implement a plugin for this. Here is a good blog about this that you can use as an example: http://smartkey.co.uk/development/securing-an-apache-ignite-cluster/

To get the security support you need to look at commercial products built on top of Ignite:
https://docs.gridgain.com/docs/security-and-audit

Comment: Based on the blog http://smartkey.co.uk/development/securing-an-apache-ignite-cluster/,  how to set the security credentials in the client side. After setting the user credentials in SecurityCredentials, how to pass it to the IgniteConfiguration

Comment: above link is for SSL Set up...One I am looking for is a way to
 pass the Client login id and password so that the server node can authenticate

Comment: It will be defined by your implementation of Security plugin.

Comment: @EvgeniiZhuravlev That link is broken.

Answer (score 3):

There are plugins that you can install. I hope you are aware of the change of plugin installations and you need to add META-INF/services/your.plugin.Provider entry to your plugin jar to activate a plugin.

If the configuration goes well, you will be able to see the plugin in node startup log. For any errors, paste it here or ask your query at Apache Ignite Users community. There are similar questions where you can find your answers.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I have rephrased my question with code snippet. Plugin is loaded on startup but getting NotSerializableException when I start the node. Highly appreciate any help that can be provided..Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while this question was asked but I thought to answer it for the new Apache Ignite version. This is applicable for Apache Ignite v.2.7.0 and above.

Apache Ignite does not provide these kinds of security capabilities with its open-source version. One can either implement it on your own or use commercial Gridgain distribution.

[Here](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/plugins) are the steps to implement a custom plugin.

One would need to implement **GridSecurityProcessor** which would be used to authenticate the joining node.

This blog has detailed steps that can be followed to write a custom security plugin.

https://www.bugdbug.com/post/how-to-secure-apache-ignite-cluster