# Apache Ignite Authorization

Tags: ignite

I am looking for apache ignite authorization examples . But i cannot find any on internet.
If any of you have implemented ignite authorization then con you tell me how to perform authorization.

I have implemented the authentication from the following link.
https://medium.com/@aamargajbhiye/how-to-secure-apache-ignite-cluster-cd595b99ec5e

but it does not depict the authorization code.

Question Edit.

I am unable to get the client credentials at the server end.

Please help me to find that object which contains all the detials of client .
such as username,operation performed like cache_put,cache_remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/46151311/36498

Autorization is not implemented in Apache Ignite, you can use some 3rd party Security plugin (usually GridGain, but I have seen other attempts at its implementation) for that or try to devise your own.

Comment: http://smartkey.co.uk/development/securing-an-apache-ignite-cluster/  

THis links says : 404 not found.

Comment: Try wayback machine: http://web.archive.org/web/20200117144230/http://smartkey.co.uk/development/securing-an-apache-ignite-cluster/